# Can not see google map in debug mode after release

Tags: android, google-maps

After releasing my application successfully (google map works great in production)..i cant see map in debugging mode any more...its throw me the exception -

```
 Authorization failure.                                                                          
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.                                                                        
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
API   Key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

in my google_maps_key.xml(debug folder) i set the key that is triggered in the exception (same key as in prod) also i did work with different api key before release and also try to switch to it..but with no success...any advice ? thanks

Comment: The package name is the same?

Comment: where it can be set differently?

Comment: Are you using the same keystore for the debug and release versions of the application?

Comment: You can set different package names using product flavors, but maybe your problem is that you have two diferent signing configs, one for debug and other for release. Probabily you need to add to your google developer console the key for the debug config. You can find this debug.keystore in the .android dir

Comment: where exactly i can find  the key for the debug config in developer console?

Comment: ok found the  debug.keystore..what to do with it ? how to open it ?

Comment: You can use this `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android 
` When complete copy and paste the `SHA1` to your google developer console

Comment: Ok.thanks.will it change anything with the releas ? I mean i dont want that next time i will upload apk to prod..i will not see the map...cause now my package is related to prod sha...

Comment: The question is - every time i m switching from debug to releae i have to change the sha in consule ?

Comment: Or can i define in one key -two rows :my package plus release sha and my package plus debug sha?

Comment: two rows, one for the debug sha and other for the release sha

Comment: Thank you @newhouse..i will try that and will update if working.

Comment: Thank you @newhouse  :)  ..actually the solution was very easy...i have just added in the same key another row off package and sha..and it works!